# PHP array as variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to PHP, I have this code:

```
if(!$form['profile_hunter']['field_profile_hunter_location']['und']['0']['value']['#default_value']){
    $form['profile_hunter']['field_profile_hunter_location']['und']['0']['value']['#default_value'] = $default_city;
  }
```

it's working but I don't like it to be that long, so I change:

```
$form_location = $form['profile_hunter']['field_profile_hunter_location']['und']['0']['value']['#default_value'];
if(!$form_location){
  $form_location = $city;
}
```

Then it's not working, why?

Comment: Ellaborate on "not working"...

Answer (score 3):

It's because when you assign $form_location, it is making a copy of the data. In order for both variables to "point" to the same data, you would need to use the reference operator, example:

```
$var = &$some_var;
```

and in your case:

```
$form_location = &$form['profile_hunter']['field_profile_hunter_location']['und']['0']['value']['#default_value'];
if(!$form_location){
  $form_location = $default_city;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Answer (score 1):

Because your code is assigning to `$form_location`, but not the actual value in the array.

The assignment makes `$form_location` refer to something different. The fact that its former value happened to be copied out of an array is irrelevant.

In C/C++, you could do something like this using pointers, but most higher level languages don't support it since it tends to be error prone.

Anyway, you could set a variable to the innermost array, since arrays are stored by reference. This would reduce the amount of code you need, while avoiding the problems introduced by taking a reference directly to an array element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$form_location = $form['profile_hunter']['field_profile_hunter_location']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'];
if(empty($form_location)){
  $form['profile_hunter']['field_profile_hunter_location']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $city;
}
```

You should probably use 'empty', that is a Drupal convention. Also "0" is not a string, but a number, so you don't need quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer! Thanks to Tony!

It should be

```
$form_location = &$form['profile_hunter']['field_profile_hunter_location']['und']['0']['value']['#default_value'];
```

The "&" means to pass by reference, without it would be to pass by value.